# Why does the Software Center not have a button for removing recently installed packages?

Tags: software-center

This is so obvious that there should be a button for removing latest installed software. Why is there no button for it? This would be a great feature.

Comment: You should file this as a bug report: [Instructions here](http://$SITEURL$/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a [Paper Cut](https://launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts) or a Feature request for [Ubuntu Software Center](https://launchpad.net/software-center)
It's a good idea.